# Linux -malign-double and clib

Tags: linux, alignment, physx

Linux (Ubuntu 14.04), gcc, c/c++ project.
I have middleware (nvidia PhysX) that needs -malign-double in compile options (my app is x86 32bit) but when I add it to project flags some system structures (stat64, aiocb64, etc...) that contain off64_t (expanded to long long) got their alignment changed (long long is now 8 bytes alinged not 4) and fucntions like stat64, aio_read64 do not work anymore - is there any solution for this problem ?
(do i need to compile own version of clib and others - this sounds crazy to me)
for now only IO and large files handling functions seems to got affected - but i need large (>4GB) files handling in the first place.

Any ideas how to solve this.
(I cannot close PhysX in some .so file and expose interface to it's clases as I need most of them anyway)